# json removed if nested class repo is added to spring boot project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i am new to spring-boot, i am getting a strange problem.
i am using repository to get reviews of a movie

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Review, Integer> {

    @Query("select rev from Review rev where rev.gymId=:gymId")
    Page findByMovieId(@Param("movieId") Integer movieId, Pageable page);

}
```

when i tried to getting reviews i am getting below json

```
 {
            "id": 1,
            "rating": 4,
            "movieId":6
            "movie":{
                id:6,
                name:"edge of tomorrow"
             } 
  }
```

problem is that when i am adding repository of Movie to my project.

```
{
                "id": 1,
                "rating": 4,
                "movieId":6
}
```

can anyone help me in this.

what is happening here?

below is my Review Pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "review", schema = "public")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Review.countAll", query = "SELECT COUNT(x) FROM Review x")
})
public class Review implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    private Integer rating;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Movie movie;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "consumer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Consumer consumer;

    //setter getter
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you use [Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html) in your project (I see `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation).

To solve this issue you can, for example, add parameter `exported=false` to `@RepositoryRestResource` of your `Movie` repo.

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302168/5380322).