# Spring data rest status 500 for entity with relation

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have two entities with a relation one to many

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;

    private String company;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    private List<Item> items;
}



public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long quantity;
}
```

Both entities have a @RepositoryRestResrouce and when I try to post in the /orders collction a new Order with Items like:

```
{
  "userName":"Marco",
  "company":"MP",
  "items":[
        {"name":"CD","quantity":"10"},
        {"name":"DVD","quantity":"5"}
   ]
 }
```

I have an internal server error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Item] for value 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI name. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Item] for value 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI name. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Order["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:236) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:193) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:141) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Item] for value 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI name. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Order["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:360) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:308) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2938) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.example.springdatarest.domain.entity.Item] for value 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI name. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.convert(UriToEntityConverter.java:119) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.6.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:518) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI name. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

I know that I can use the association resource but I would like to know how I can create an Order with Items in one single POST.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just [add parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories) `exported=false` to `@RepositoryRestResrouce` annotation in your `Item` repo. Then you can create `Order` with `Item` in one request:

```
{
    "userName": "Marco",
    "company": "MP",
    "items": [
        {
             "name": "CD",
             "quantity": "10"
        },
        { 
             "name": "DVD",
             "quantity": "5" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I recommend you to add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true` to `items` in `Order` to make items fully managed by `Order`.

Additional [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198584/5380322).

---

If you want to work with Order and Item independently you can leave all as is but first create you items:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/items
{
        {
             "name": "CD",
             "quantity": "10"
        },
        { 
             "name": "DVD",
             "quantity": "5" 
        }
}
```

then create Order that contains them:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/orders
{
    {
        "userName": "Marco",
        "company": "MP",
        "items": [
            "http://localhost:8080/items/1",
            "http://localhost:8080/items/2"
        ]
    }
}
```

You use `@JoinColumn` annotation with `items` - so I think you must implement [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198175/spring-data-rest-managing-all-entities-with-one-crud-repository/47198584#comment81371097_47198584) between `Order` and `Items` in that case...

---

And please don't post JSON in one line ))

Comment: It worked but I would like to know if there is a way to post the whole Order resource without having to create the Items resource first, but keep exposing Items as a resource too

Comment: @MarcoPrado You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)

Comment: could you show me an example, I guess projections are used when you want to omit certain fields on the request result

Comment: @MarcoPrado if you want to expose `Item`s as *independent* resources then you cannot managed them by `Order`. But you can always implement your custom controller...

Comment: yes, I guess it is more a problem of how I am modeling my domain and the resource exposure.

Comment: @MarcoPrado So did you manage to find a way to expose the `Item` resources as independently and have them managed by `Order` at the same time? I'm trying to achieve the same thing now. Any insight?

Comment: This works but does not update the foreign key column in items with the record id of the order

Answer (score 3):

Add @RestResource(exported = false) in the items:

```
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;

    private String company;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1121